# JPA @query is not working when date value is null during insert

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have written below java code in my JPA repository.

```
@Query("insert into table (date_colum) value(:dateValue)",nativeQuery= true)
public int insertData(@Param("dateValue") dateValue);
```

**Above code is working perfect when dateValue column is having some value. But when value of dateValue cloumn is null in that case it will giving the below error .**

```
Error : ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected date got binary
```

Any solution please , help is appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure is a `date`. the error is quite clear, the :dateValue is not a date.

Comment: No , I am sure that is date only , this working perfect when passing value is date but not worked in case of null value

Comment: What is the actual type you are using for date?

Comment: Date i am using

Answer (score 1):

If We add **@Temporal** to your Date parameter, Spring Data knows how to present that parameter to Hibernate, even if it is null:

The code is like as below.

```
@Query("insert into table (date_colum) value(:dateValue)",nativeQuery= true)
public int insertData(@Param("dateValue") @Temporal java.util.Date dateValue);
```